# Prepared statements in SQL query while saving JSON data in PHP

Tags: mysql, json, prepared-statement, php-7

I have simple php code for parsing some data from a JSON file and saving them into mysql database. But it's showing following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'my_name' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode.php on line 25
```

My php code is following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (my_name, hobby, other) VALUES ($row['my_name'], $row['hobby'], $row['other'])"; //line 25

mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
```

Why is it showing syntax error? Is there anything wrong in the query?

Comment: @Kirk Beard i used single quatation as you suggested. but still showing the same error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode.php on line 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose interpolated placeholders in curly braces, i.e. `$row['my_name']` -> `{$row['my_name']}`:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (my_name, hobby, other) VALUES ({$row['my_name']}, {$row['hobby']}, {$row['other']})";
```

---

This addresses only PHP syntax. 
The SQL syntax error you get now is the next issue. 
The simplest thing to "fix" this would be to include additional apostrophes around placeholders, i.e.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (my_name, hobby, other) VALUES ('{$row['my_name']}', '{$row['hobby']}', '{$row['other']}')";
```

**BUT DON'T DO THAT,** since this code is an example of a classic **SQL Injection  vulnerability**.

Consider using a [**prepared statement**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead — this eliminates the PHP's string interpolation altogether.

Comment: it's showing another error: Error: INSERT INTO table1 (my_name, hobby, other) VALUES (Susanne, football play, other/data)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'play, other/data)' at line 1

Comment: @kov, updated the answer. Your real solution is to use a prepared statement.

Comment: I used prepare statement, but it's showing syntax error again. the description is updated above.

Comment: @kov, you've done a great job, but it would make more sense to ask a new question in this case, since too much has been changed since the original version... 
The solution now is to set `$a`, `$b` and `$c` _before_ the `$stmt->bind_param` call, and to remove apostrophes from the assignments, i.e. `$a = {$row['my_name']};`

Comment: Now it gives another error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode.php on line 16

Comment: Sorry, a typo, my fault. This will work: 
`$a = $row['my_name'];`

Comment: i tried it too. it gives another error: Error: INSERT INTO table1(my_name, hobby, other) VALUES (?,?,?);
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1

Comment: try removing the semicolon from the SQL, `$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (my_name, hobby, other) VALUES (?,?,?)";`

Comment: i removed semicolon, but still showing same error : $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (my_name, hobby, other) VALUES (?,?,?)";

Comment: @kov, this has shifted into SQL domain from PHP, could you please ask another question? I'd gladly help you in a different thread, as well as many SQL experts on StackOverflow... Thanks!

Comment: here is the new question. please respond there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049436/syntax-error-in-using-prepared-statement-for-inserting-json-data-into-mysql-data